# Flex - Change position of scrollbar to the top of a HorizontalList component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, scrollbar, horizontallist

By default, the Horizontal ScrollBar of a HorizontalList component will be at the bottom. Is there a way to reposition it so it is at the top?

Just for clarity, I do not mean moving the scroll position using either scrollToIndex or horizontalScrollPosition or similar, but the actual physical position of the scrollbar component.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for something similar myself a while ago and found [this post](http://yourpalmark.com/2008/06/18/reposition-scrollbars-in-flex-components/). I eventually ended up solving my problem in another way, so didn't use that solution, however it might work for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do the same thing previously. I had to dig around in the base classes (to handle some masking/positioning issues) and this is what I came up with:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import mx.controls.HorizontalList;
    import mx.core.EdgeMetrics;

    public class ReverseHList extends HorizontalList
    {
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var w:Number = unscaledWidth;
            var h:Number = unscaledHeight;
            var vm:EdgeMetrics = viewMetrics;
            if (horizontalScrollBar && horizontalScrollBar.visible)
            {
                horizontalScrollBar.setActualSize(w - vm.left - vm.right,
                                                  horizontalScrollBar.minHeight);
                horizontalScrollBar.move(vm.left, vm.top);

                horizontalScrollBar.enabled = enabled;
            }

            var mask:DisplayObject = maskShape;

            var wd:Number = w - vm.left - vm.right;
            var ht:Number = h - vm.top - vm.bottom;

            mask.width = wd < 0 ? 0 : wd;
            mask.height = ht < 0 ? 0 : ht;

            mask.x = vm.left;
            mask.y = vm.top + vm.bottom;
        }

        override protected function adjustListContent(unscaledWidth:Number = -1,
                                       unscaledHeight:Number = -1):void
        {
            super.adjustListContent(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var lcx:Number = viewMetrics.left + listContent.leftOffset;
            var lcy:Number = (viewMetrics.top + listContent.topOffset) + viewMetrics.bottom;
            listContent.move(lcx, lcy);
        }

    }
}
```