# Move scrollbar in Flex3 UI

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex3, scrollbar

I need to show the vertical scrollbar, when visible, not on the right (default), but on the left side of the screen. 
The application is written in Java, running on Websphere, with UI in Flex 3. 
The container with the scrollbar is VBox, custom object extended from the VBox, and in another case DataGrid. 
Here is what I've tried so far:

This draws the scrollbar on the left at initial rendering, and immediately moves it to the right afterwards.

```
   if( verticalScrollBar && verticalScrollBar.visible )
     {
       verticalScrollBar.x = -verticalScrollBar.width;
     }
```

This seems to be ignored completely:

```
protected override function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number ):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );
    if( verticalScrollBar && verticalScrollBar.visible )
    {
        verticalScrollBar.x = -verticalScrollBar.width;
    }
}
```

Also tried setting

```
verticalScrollBar.x = 0;
```

did not make a difference.

These are the only suggestions I've found [online](http://yourpalmark.com/2008/06/18/reposition-scrollbars-in-flex-components/) and on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615074/flex-change-position-of-scrollbar-to-the-top-of-a-horizontallist-component).
How can this be done?

Comment: Easy as pie with Flex4. Can't be done - without major hacking - in Flex3 (afaik).

Comment: That's too bad. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
override public function validateDisplayList():void {
    super.validateDisplayList();
    if (verticalScrollBar && verticalScrollBar.visible) {
        verticalScrollBar.x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you noticed that this is not `updateDisplayList` method but `validateDisplayList`? It worked for me, other than that I don't know how to help you.

Comment: yes, I changed the overridden method name, as you suggested.  But it doesn't appear to be called, either.